# How to define a string literal containing non-ASCII characters?

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I'm programming in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008.
I need to define a string literal containing the character "÷" equivalent to Chr(247).
I understand that internally VS uses UTF-16 encoding, but when the source file is written to disk it contains the single byte value F7 for this character.

This source file is processed by another program that uses UTF-8 encoding by default, so it fails to interpret this character correctly, attempting to combine it with the following single-byte character.
What encoding would correctly interpret the single byte F7 as the single character ÷?

Alternatively, is there a way of expressing a non-ASCII literal that uses only ASCII characters - like using some kind of escape sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, i always thought that by default VS uses UTF-8 to save files. But ÷ is F7 in encoding ISO 8859-1. If this is not enough for you go here: [how to change source file encoding in csharp project (visual studio / msbuild machine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840065/how-to-change-source-file-encoding-in-csharp-project-visual-studio-msbuild-mac)

Comment: If you aren't specifying encoding then the file is written in ASCII(7 bit data).  For the full ASCII character set I use winndows-1252 encoding.

Comment: In the Western European locale, VS2008 uses the Windows code page to save files unless there are characters that won't fit! So many thanks, that was exactly the pointer I needed.

Comment: @dbasnett, no. i can be sure only about C# editor in VS, because i mainly use it. so, it saves in UTF-8, which is backward compatible with ASCII.