# Error comparing french characters in a c++ string

Tags: c++, string, file-encodings

I was wondering if any of you could help me with a problem I'm having.  Currently I have a function that takes in a c-style string, creates a temporary c++ style string and store the c string into it, and uses the find_first_not_of command to look for invalid characters, some of which include french characters like 'à'.  However, when I pass in a string containing french characters, it doesn't recognize them as valid.

I am using visual studio 2013 on Windows 8, and a few people have told me that the issue is that how VS encodes it's files is different then how it encodes input from the command prompt, but I do not know how to fix that.  Do any of you know how I would go about doing this? Or is is a different problem with my code entirely?

My code for the function is as follow:

```
bool checkValidCharacters(const char* input)
{
    std::string checkString(input);
    bool validCharacters = false;
    std::size_t found = checkString.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZàâäèêëîôùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊÎÏÔÙÛÜŸÇ-. ");
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        printf("Error: Invalid character: %c", input[found]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("All characters valid\n");
        validCharacters = true;
    }
    return validCharacters;
}
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: if `à` is a Unicode then you need to use a `wstring`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how (note that my test with a UTF-8 euro symbol didn't display properly with the raster font, but still worked).

Comment: Just to confirm your code works fine http://rextester.com/UGB48805. (As you said, the problem must be something else). This may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276757/change-encoding-on-a-per-file-or-per-extension-basis or https://vlasovstudio.com/fix-file-encoding/