# Urdu language issue, base64 stores long unreadable string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I am assigning Urdu text to a variable in c# and inserting it into database (SendMessages table), it saves Urdu message perfectly without any modification, great but when that message is received in any mobile handset then it appears as ??????????????????????, why ? i checked it with all urdu compatible handsets which receive other urdu messages perfectly but not this one.

Code asp.net:

```
String MessageLanguage= Convert.ToString(ViewState["LanguageCode"]); //

                        if (MessageLanguage == "ur")
                        {
                            String UrduMsg = ComplaintCode +" "+"اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے";
                            quebiz.Insert(lblContact.Text, UrduMsg, null, Convert.ToInt32(lblComplainantID.Text), null, null);
                            ViewState["LanguageCode"] = null;

                        }
```

In simple words, urdu message being passed from C# into sql table is fine and perfect, not problem but after receiving same sms in handset, it doesn't work that way.  I tried base64 conversion like

```
String UrduMsg = ComplaintCode +" "+"اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے";
                            var UrduMsgBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UrduMsg);
                            var Base64EncodedUrduMsg = Convert.ToBase64String(UrduMsgBytes);
```

but it resulted in saving a long string in database like it is rendering `yu98yhr9h93h99hd9h9ash9dhas9yr090u0usjaosfhiehhw8hw`.
Collation on column is ON, column is Nvarchar(1600).
why ? help ? I am using asp.net C#.net 4.0 with sql server 2014.

Comment: You store string in database and when you read it, ????? will appear?

Comment: doesn't appear in mobile, just "?????????????????????" marks appear

Comment: Are you using **N** to insert your data to SQL Server? I'm not sure but maybe your problem is because of that.

Comment: For example : `insert into tableName(name) values(N'"+درج کردی+"')`

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. This seems identical to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720874/urdu-message-sent-from-sql-to-mobile-handset-is-in-unreadable-format You need to follow each question to its conclusion, don't just ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try `N` parameter for Insert command.

For example use:

```
insert into tableName(name) values(N'"+درج کردی+"')
```

Comment: yes but how to append N in my case ? like i am trying to put N but it throws syntax error

String UrduMsg = ComplaintCode +" "+"اپکی سثیکایت درج کردی گیؑ ھے۔ سثیکایت کوڈ یہ ہے";

how to put in this ?

Comment: @JohnNash: What `quebiz` is instance of? Maybe it has a property to set this attribute.

Comment: it's an instance of a class QueueBizz

Comment: @JohnNash Is QueueBizz your custom class? If yes, What is the implementation of Insert method of QueueBizz class?