# Express sessions flash messages with accented characters

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js application that uses express sessions.

I use the sessions to display error messages to the users, such as when they type in an invalid username/password.

The website is in German and I can't make the app display accented characters. For example, when users type a wrong password in the login form, this code uses flash to display an error message:

```
if (result === false) {
        req.session.flash = {
            type: 'danger',
            intro: 'Ooops',
            message: 'Ungültige Email und/oder Passwort. Bitte erneut versuchen.',
        };
        res.redirect(303, '/login');            
    }
```

The *message* as noted above is displayed as "Ung�ltige Email und/oder Passwort. Bitte erneut versuchen."

How do I get the flash messages to properly encode the strings when using accented characters?

Comment: Make sure that your .js file is being saved as UTF-8.

Comment: @robertklep. And how do I do that? I am writing my js files in visual Studio

Comment: I don't have any experience with Visual Studio, but perhaps [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/840082/893780) is helpful.