# Charset UTF 8 does not work when used with Ionic Framework

Tags: html, ionic-framework, meta-tags

On my web app I have characters like 'Å' and I have the meta tag  `<meta charset="utf-8" >` but these characters are not shown in the browsers. They are shown like question mark '?' .

I am using Ionic framework ? What am I missing ?

Comment: Check your file encoding and make sure it set to utf-8 as well.

Comment: What ide are you using to write your code?

Comment: I am using Visual studio

Comment: Look over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840065/how-to-change-source-file-encoding-in-csharp-project-visual-studio-msbuild-ma to change file encoding

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the file with VS and change the save options in `File` -> `Advanced Save Options` -> `Unicode (Utf8...)`

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017: `File` > `Save .... as` > Button with arrow near `Save` > `Save with Encoding`