# How to change ionic font for right to left languages?

Tags: ionic-framework, font-face, visual-studio-cordova

In VS 2015, Blank App (Apache Cordova) show Persian (Farsi) text properly, but in ionic framework Persian (Farsi) text show like this:

[image: In ionic Persian text not work properly]

I've tried to add custom font-face in these steps:

1. Add fonts to www/lib/ionic/fonts
2. make a font-face like this

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "customFont";
  src: url("../fonts/BMitra.eot?v=2.0.1");
  src: url("../lib/ionic/fonts/BMitra.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../lib/ionic/fonts/BMitra.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("../lib/ionic/fonts/BMitra.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  font-family: "customFont";
}
```

3. Test the font face both in ionic.css and style.css

But fonts still not working properly. 
Any suggestion? 
Thanks...

Comment: Wrong question, this is almost certainly a text encoding problem.

Comment: Exactly, Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32278124/1224187 thanks Hans