# Unity the Associated Script could not be loaded (no errors)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've Had this problem for a while where my scripts in Unity just refuse to compile. All of the scripts in my project are not compiling into unity. The scripts compile in visual studio for mac, but not in Unity. On all of the script import settings it says:

"No mono behavior scripts in file, or their names do not match the file names"

All of the scripts have the same class name as their file names. In the inspector, every script says "the associated script could not be loaded"

I have tried refreshing the assists, reimporting the assist, and restarting my computer multiple times, to no avail. I have updated unity from 2017.3 to 2018.1 also to no avail.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe is the encoding, Mac usually uses UTF8 and Windows uses 1252, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840065/how-to-change-source-file-encoding-in-csharp-project-visual-studio-msbuild-ma

Comment: I have seen this, but how do I change the encoding? The advanced save options was removed

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx

Comment: This link provides outdated information, Again, Microsoft removed the ability to access the advanced save options. As a reminder I am using a mac with visual studio

Comment: Ok all of my files are encoded with UTF8 so I'm not sure what you mean. Any other suggestions?