Visual Studio 2022 adds byte order mark to python files
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to develop some python.
It appears that visual studio adds byte order marks to each python file. I didn't know about these things, but these are not playing well with some tools in the python world.
Such as pipreqs: SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+FEFF
Is there a way to disable this in Visual Studio 2022, there don't appear to be many options for python files. (eg: no editorconfig creator)
And how to remove this from the files, because no editor shows them.

A workaround exists for pipreqs --encoding=utf-8-sig

this question has an answer that goes over changing what encoding a file in VS is saved as - you want to avoid saving it as UTF-with-BOM -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840065/how-to-change-source-file-encoding-in-csharp-project-visual-studio-msbuild-ma
